# what is the purpose of BufferedWriter writefile = null;

Tags: java

I have used Buffered writer a few times but there is a line of code I am not sure of its purpose. The code is below

```
BufferedWriter writefile = null;
```

I wonder if anyone could tell me what this line of code does and if it is needed.

Comment: Please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html for the tutorial about variables.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of `BufferedReader` can involve calling constructors which can throw exceptions like `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation))` because calling `FileReader` constructor may throw `FileNotFoundException` if location in `fileLocation` doesn't point to existing and accessible file.

To handle this exception we move initialization in `try` section. Theoretically we could write

```
try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
    //...
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //handle exception
}
```

but then in `finally` section we want to handle closing that reader and prevent resource leaking. So we need to add

```
finally{
     br.close();
}
```

#### Problem 1 - scope

We can't access `br` from `finally` section because it was declared in `try` section so its scope is limited to it.

Solution would be declaring it outside of `try` but initializing in try. So lets do

```
BufferedReader br;
try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
    //...
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //handle exception
}finally{
    br.close();
}
```

#### Problem 2 - usage of possibly uninitialized variable

We can't call `br.close()` because if exception will be thrown `br` will not be initialized (not even with null), so compiler can't compile such code.

Solution is to *explicitly* assign `null` to `br` before `try` section. This will allow us to know in `finally` section if `br` was properly initialized and need to be closed or not (if it still holds `null`). So we used to write code like

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
    //...
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //handle exception
}finally{
    if (br != null){
         br.close();
    }
}
```

---

Above was used pre **Java 7**, before **[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)** was introduced. Now to have same functionality as above all we need is

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation))) {
    //...
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //handle exception
}
```